# Can I allocate a series of variables on the stack based on template arguments?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, c++20

In a piece of code I'm writing, I receive packets as `uint8_t *` and `std::size_t` combination. I can register functions to call with these two parameters, based on which file descriptor the packet was received from. I use an `std::map<int, std::function<void(const uint8_t *, std::size_t)> > handlers` to keep track of which function to call.

I would like to be able to (indirectly) register functions with arbitrary arguments. I already have a function like this to transform from the `uint8_t *` and `std::size_t` to separate variables:

```
int unpack(const uint8_t *buf, std::size_t len) { return 0; }

template <typename T, typename... Types>
int unpack(const uint8_t *buf, std::size_t len, T &var1, Types... var2) {
  static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable<T>::value, "unpack() only works for primitive types");
  if (len < sizeof(T)) return -1;
  var1 = *reinterpret_cast<const T *>(buf);
  const auto sum = unpack(buf + sizeof(T), len - sizeof(T), var2...);
  const auto ret = (sum == -1) ? -1 : sum + sizeof(T);
  return ret;
}
```

My question is: Is it possible with C++20 to auto-generate a function that convers from `uint8_t *` and `std::size_t` to the arguments that a passed function needs?

I would like to be able to do this:

```
void handler(unsigned int i) { ... }

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
/* some code generating an fd */
handlers[fd] = function_returning_an_unpacker_function_that_calls_handler(handler);
```

**edit:** I realize I went a bit too short on my answer, as some mentioned (thanks!).

I am wondering if it is possible (and if so, how?) to implement the `function_returning_an_unpacker_function_that_calls_handler` function. I started out doing something like this (written from memory):

```
template<typename... Types>
std::function<void(const uint8_t * buf, std::size_t)>
function_returning_an_unpacker_function_that_calls_handler(std::function<void(Types...)> function_to_call) {
  const auto ret = new auto([fun](const uint8_t * buf, std::size_t len) -> void {
    const auto unpack_result = unpack(buf, len, list_of_variables_based_on_template_params);
    if(unpack_result == -1) return nullptr;
    function_to_call(list_of_variables_based_on_template_params);
  };
  return ret;
}
```

This is also why I supplied the `unpack` function. The problem I'm encountering is that I'm struggling with the `list_of_variables_based_on_template_params` bit. I haven't found any way to generate a list of variables that I can repeat identically in two places.
I also looked a little bit into using `std::tuple::tie` and friends, but I didn't see a solution there either.

Comment: I think you went a bit to minimal in your example. It's at least not clear to me what you want the function to do here. Your `unpack` return an `int`. Where does the separate variables and mapping to your handlers come into it? Isn't that the part you want help with?

Comment: Also, `unpack(buf + sizeof(T), len - sizeof(T), var2...);` has more than 2 arguments and your unpack function declaration has only two: `int unpack(const uint8_t *buf, std::size_t len)`.

Comment: @user17732522 you are right! Thanks!

Comment: @super Updated the question a bit. Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: Did you look at std::integer_sequence examples?

Comment: @MarcGlisse Not yet, will do.

Comment: @user17732522, ohh yeah my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is very similar to the first one, but it leverages the use of CTAD and `std::function` to figure out the function signature.

Creates a tuple based on the function signature, and passes both the argument types and the elements from the tuple on to `unpack`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstring>
#include <functional>

int unpack(const uint8_t *buf, std::size_t len) { return 0; }

template <typename T, typename... Types>
int unpack(const uint8_t *buf, std::size_t len, T &var1, Types&... var2) {
  static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable<T>::value, "unpack() only works for primitive types");
  if (len < sizeof(T)) return -1;
  var1 = *reinterpret_cast<const T *>(buf);
  std::cout << "In unpack " << var1 << "\n";
  const auto sum = unpack(buf + sizeof(T), len - sizeof(T), var2...);
  const auto ret = (sum == -1) ? -1 : sum + sizeof(T);
  return ret;
}

template<typename T, typename R, typename... Args>
std::function<void(const uint8_t * buf, std::size_t)>
unpack_wrapper_impl(T function_to_call, std::function<R(Args...)>) {
    return [function_to_call](const uint8_t *buf, std::size_t len) -> void {
        std::tuple<std::decay_t<Args>...> tup;
        std::apply([&](auto&... args) {
            unpack(buf, len, args...);
        }, tup);
        std::apply(function_to_call, tup);
    };
}

template<typename T>
std::function<void(const uint8_t * buf, std::size_t)>
unpack_wrapper(T&& function_to_call) {
    return unpack_wrapper_impl(std::forward<T>(function_to_call), std::function{function_to_call});
}

void test(int a, int b) {
    std::cout << a << " " << b << "\n";
}

int main() {
    int a= 5, b = 9;
    uint8_t* buf = new uint8_t[8];
    std::memcpy(buf, &a, 4);
    std::memcpy(buf + 4, &b, 4);

    auto f = unpack_wrapper(test);

    f(buf, 8);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's possible, just annoying to write.

First you need a trait to get parameters from a function type:

```
template <typename T>
struct FuncTraits {};

#define GEN_FUNC_TRAITS_A(c, v, ref, noex) \
    template <typename R, typename ...P> \
    struct FuncTraits<R(P...) c v ref noex> \
    { \
        template <template <typename...> typename T> \
        using ApplyParams = T<P...>; \
    };

#define GEN_FUNC_TRAITS_B(c, v, ref) \
    GEN_FUNC_TRAITS_A(c, v, ref,) \
    GEN_FUNC_TRAITS_A(c, v, ref, noexcept)

#define GEN_FUNC_TRAITS_C(c, v) \
    GEN_FUNC_TRAITS_B(c, v,) \
    GEN_FUNC_TRAITS_B(c, v, &) \
    GEN_FUNC_TRAITS_B(c, v, &&)

#define GEN_FUNC_TRAITS(c) \
    GEN_FUNC_TRAITS_C(c,) \
    GEN_FUNC_TRAITS_C(c, volatile)

GEN_FUNC_TRAITS()
GEN_FUNC_TRAITS(const)
```

Then some templates to analyze what kind of callable (function, function pointer, or a  functor) you got, and apply the trait accordingly:

```
template <typename T> struct RemoveMemPtr {using type = T;};
template <typename T, typename C> struct RemoveMemPtr<T C::*> {using type = T;};

template <typename T>
struct ToFuncType {};

template <typename T>
requires std::is_function_v<std::remove_pointer_t<T>>
struct ToFuncType<T> {using type = std::remove_pointer_t<T>;};

template <typename T>
requires requires {&T::operator();}
struct ToFuncType<T>
{
    using type = typename RemoveMemPtr<decltype(&T::operator())>::type;
};
```

Then you can make a templated functor that automatically unwraps the arguments. Since `Unwrap()` must be called in order, and function arguments are evaluated in unspecified order, we need a tuple (or something similar) that accepts a braced list:

```
template <typename T>
T Unpack(char *&, std::size_t &)
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
    return {};
}

template <typename F>
struct WrapFunctor
{
    template <typename ...P>
    struct Impl
    {
        std::decay_t<F> func;
        
        void operator()(char *p, std::size_t n)
        {
            std::apply(func, std::tuple{Unpack<P>(p, n)...});
        }
    };
};

template <typename F>
auto Wrap(F &&func)
{
    using Functor = typename FuncTraits<typename ToFuncType<std::remove_cvref_t<F>>::type>::template ApplyParams<WrapFunctor<F>::template Impl>;
    return Functor{std::forward<F>(func)};
}
```

Finally, some tests:

```
void foo(int, float, char)
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    Wrap(foo)(nullptr, 42);
    Wrap(&foo)(nullptr, 42);
    Wrap([](int, float, char){std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';})(nullptr, 42);
}
```

I've changed the signature of `Unpack()` to take the parameters by reference and unpack one variable at a time.

---

Almost forgot: `var1 = *reinterpret_cast<const T *>(buf);` is a strict aliasing violation and UB. Prefer `memcpy`.

Comment: CTAD and `std::function` can figure out the function parameters from a function type.

Comment: @super Yeah, but that feels like a misuse of it. I'd rather have my own trait.

Comment: Ok. I'll post it as an alternative approach.

Comment: Funny that I asked a similar question about extracting callable traists yesterday and someone suggests that we can use callable traits of boost. But you are missing half of your specilizations(it is 48, not 24). you can check `is_function` in cpp ref for it. you need an additional struct with `R(P......) c v ref noex` in your specialization. But it is a great idea to use macros to generate them anyway.

Comment: @Afshin That's intentional, because I can't deserialize an `...` argument.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat oh,you are right..